# Mod_rewrite check if php file exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a few mod_rewrite rules. Everything is working fine at the moment. At the moment my generic URLs look like this:

```
http://website.com/about-us
http://website.com/privacy
```

At the moment, these 2 links are mod_rewritten to `content.php`, because `about-us` and `privacy` don't exist as .php files, but rather, their content is stored in a database, which content.php retrieves.

I have another url:

```
http://website.com/contact-us
```

Which does exist as a .php file, because it contains custom data.
How can I check to see if `contact-us.php` exists. If it does, redirect `website.com/contact-us` to `website.com/contact-us.php`, otherwise, redirect to `website.com/content.php`

Below is my mod_rewrite file as it stands:

```
RewriteEngine On

# I want the following condition and rule to look to see if the .php file exists,
# and if it does, redirect to the physical page, otherwise, redirect to content.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+).php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.php$ [L]


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$ /content.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(product1|product2|product3)/(designer1|designer2|designer3)$ /search.php?productType=$1&designer=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^sale/(product1|product2|product3)$ /search.php?sale=1&productType=$1 [L]
```

If you need any further information, please let me know!
I appreciate the replies :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change your `.htaccess` code to

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not an existing dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not an existing file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f # and page.php exists

# redirect to the physical page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# otherwise, redirect to content.php
RewriteRule ^ /content.php [L]

RewriteRule ^sale/(product[123])$ /search.php?sale=1&productType=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(product[123])/(designer[123])$ /search.php?productType=$1&designer=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I've also simplified the pattern matching for your other `RewriteRule`s. Notice the use of `[QSA]` to forward any extra query parameters automatically and `[NC]` to make the match case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately, its coming up with a 500 internal server error :(

Comment: Remove the `/` between `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}`.

Comment: Also take a look at the simpler pattern matching for  your other `RewriteRule`s.

Comment: Just tested it in full, unfortunately even if the page doesn't exist, its still trying to redirect to the physical page, and not content.php

Comment: Please try using `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` everywhere i.e. replace `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}` with `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`. Before making this change make sure this isn't a browser cache issue by clearing it and testing first.

Answer (score 2):

I would use this:

```
#
# redirect first the evidences:
#
RewriteRule ^(product1|product2|product3)/(designer1|designer2|designer3)$ /search.php?    productType=$1&designer=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^sale/(product1|product2|product3)$ /search.php?sale=1&productType=$1 [L]

#
# redirect then the generality:
#
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%%{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

#
# all other requests are rewritten to /content.php:
#
RewriteRule ^ /content.php [L]
```