# Check if url has been entered

Tags: php, url

I need a piece of code that checks to see if a URL has been entered.

```
 $url = 'localhost/index.php';
 if($url){
    echo "index.php is correct";
 } else {
    header('localhost/...');
 }
```

Comment: You want to validate the URL or just check if "index.php" is here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to check if the **variable** `$url` is set, then you should be using  [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/isset).

If you are trying to check if the variable `$url` has a **value** that **is not** NULL, FALSE, 0 or an empty string, then you should be using [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

If you are trying to check and see if a file exists, you should be using **Apache**'s `.htaccess` files to let PHP know. ([See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19618885/3511423)) Alternatively, you can try to parse the URL for the path, and use [`file_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and [`is_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) to determine if the path exists and is actually a file.

If you want to know if the variable's value is a **valid type of URL**, you are looking for  [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)