# htaccess breaking urls without an extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was using this in my `.htaccess` to remove the .php from the URLs:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Problem is I have URLs ending like this:

`/services/marketing.php` (which correctly displays without the extension - /services/marketing)

`/services`  (which breaks when I put the rule in. This is a directory that by default is serving the index.php contained within it)

Anyone know how I can write the `.htaccess` rules so it allows both those styles of URL to work?

Comment: please format code appropriately by indenting with 4 spaces

Comment: I thought I had, sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mod\_rewrite check if php file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618751/mod-rewrite-check-if-php-file-exists)

Comment: You want to check via a RewriteCond whether what was requested exists as a physical file, when `.php` is appended to it - see duplicate for an example.

Comment: He had @Luuklag - but the formatting got confused when he didn't include a space between his first line. It's silly that that breaks it.. but oh well!

Comment: Thanks @CBroe
I'll take a look at that now. My issue may be slightly different as /services/marketing.php is a physical file and the /services url is serving up an index.php in the /services directory. I'll look at that link and see if I can use it to help me solve this

Comment: Yes, and that is why you only want to rewrite the ones for which you can find an actual .php file. `/services` will then work the same way as it did before (meaning, the web server will automatically serve the index document), because there is no `/services.php` file present, so that you don’t rewrite that one to begin with.

Comment: Totally makes sense @CBroe. I just have to get the code write that does that test (htaccess is not my strong point). The one from the answer you linked to isn't currently working for me, but that's likely an oversight on my part

Comment: Sorted. Thanks @Cbroe

Answer (score 0):

The link @CBroe shared answers this - [Mod_rewrite check if php file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618751/mod-rewrite-check-if-php-file-exists)

The line I was missing was:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f
```