# How to remove the .php extension in this .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./serve.php?id=$1
```

So first of all, I have a system that works with ids... so if somebody searches for https:// it opens the serve page and then works with the id. But as an example I have some fixed pages too like login.php, signup.php, home.php and others. I want to remove the .php extension but I also don't want that if somebody searches for https://example.com/home it opens up the server.php page and uses home as id, but it should work as home.php and I have problems doing that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mod\_rewrite check if php file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618751/mod-rewrite-check-if-php-file-exists)